# Pig Latin Program - Javascript (not working)

Tags: javascript

so i have to make a pig latin translator for my javascript class.
i'm supposed to enter a sentence for example, `this is a test` and it will fully translate the sentence into pig latin.
my problem is that my code will only translate the first word. 
help please

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var word = "";
    var letter1 = "";
    var letter2 = "";
    var result = "";
    var sentence = "";
    var ES = "";
    var BR = "<br />";


    document.write("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!" + BR);

    word = prompt("Enter a word: (type in -1 to quit)");
    document.write(result + ES);

    letter1 = word.substr(0,1);
    letter2 = word.substr(1,1);

    if (letter1 == "a" || letter1 == "e" || letter1 == "i" || letter1 == "o" || letter1 == "u" || letter1 == "y") {
        result  = word + "way";
    }

    else if (letter2 == "a" || letter2 == "e" || letter2 == "i" || letter2 == "o" || letter2 == "u" || letter2 == "y") {
        result = word.substr(1, word.length - 1) + letter1 + "ay"; 
    }   
    else {
        result = word.substr(2, word.length - 1) + letter1 + letter2 + "ay";

    }

    while (word != "-1") {
        word = prompt("Enter a word: (type in -1 to quit)");

        if (word != "-1") {
            document.write(result);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug your code?

Comment: the program runs, it`s just when i enter more than one word, it only translates the first word.

Comment: Well, look at the last lines of your code. `word = prompt("Enter a word: (type in -1 to quit)");` asks for a new word, but you never to anything with it.  All you do is `if (word != "-1") { document.write(result); }`, but you never actually change `result`. Did you expect `result` to somehow update by itself because `word` changed? JavaScript is still executed from top to bottom, it doesn't magically jump back.

Comment: okay, so how do i go about changing the result?

Comment: You have to execute the same logic that you have for the first word. Of course you don't want to copy&paste it. There are multiple ways to reuse this code: Either put the whole block into a loop or create a function.

Comment: thank you! i understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the code you want to repeat inside the while loop

```
while (word != '-1') {
        word = prompt("Enter a word: (type in -1 to quit)");
        document.write(result + ES);
        ...

        if (word != '-1') {
            document.write(result);
        }
    }
```